# Firebase Realtime-Database listeners not working

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to get some data stored in Firebase, but the listeners i've added are not working. The weird thing is that sometime it works, and sometime it doesn't, with the code unchanged. Is this a Firebase problem, a problem from my device, or a problem from my code?

I tried to debug the app with breakpoints inside the onDataChange() and onCancelled() methods, and they are not reached, but the method addedFestivalsListener() returns the listener object, and it's not null.
Also, the reference to Firebase is created, and the listener is added correctly.

The database structure looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ZP4e.jpg).

```java
private ValueEventListener addedFestivalsListener(){
    ValueEventListener addedListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            allFestivals.clear();
            for (DataSnapshot festSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                Festival f = festSnapshot.getValue(Festival.class);
                allFestivals.add(f);
            }
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage());
        }
    };
    return addedListener;
}
```

```java
dRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("festivals");
dRef.addValueEventListener(addedFestivalsListener());
```

The only thing i got in Logcat is a message like this: Verification of addedFestivalsListener() took 106.237ms

I added a listener to verify the connection to firebase and the output looks like this:

```
2019-05-30 17:12:44.023 30517-30517/? D/FestivalsFragment: onDataChange: not connected
2019-05-30 17:22:02.492 30517-30517/? D/FestivalsFragment: onDataChange: connected
2019-05-30 17:22:02.492 30517-30517/? D/FestivalsFragment: onDataChange: connected
2019-05-30 17:22:05.922 30517-30517/? D/FestivalsFragment: onDataChange: not connected
2019-05-30 17:22:05.923 30517-30517/? D/FestivalsFragment: onDataChange: not connected
2019-05-30 17:48:42.819 30517-30517/? D/FestivalsFragment: onDataChange: connected
2019-05-30 17:48:42.819 30517-30517/? D/FestivalsFragment: onDataChange: connected
```

Comment: Please only use the `android-studio` tag for questions about the Android Studio IDE itself. For questions about Android programming in general, use the `android` tag.

Comment: how is your database structure

Comment: I edited the question to add an image of the database structure

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Please responde with @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo I am just trying to retrieve some data from Firebase in order to display it, but the listeners that provide this feature are not firing, so the list that should contain the data is empty and there is nothing to show on the UI.

Comment: @AlexandruNicoara Is your `onDataChange` even triggered?

Comment: @AlexMamo No, and I don't know why. Sorry if i didn't explain it clear enough.

Comment: Does `Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage());` print something? Are you sure you have internet connection on the device?

Comment: Yes, I have internet connection on the device, and there is no error message. The `onCancelled` method is not even triggered.

Comment: @AlexMamo I noticed that disabling and enabling back the wi-fi on my device might fix this problem, so maybe the problem is the internet connection?

Comment: @AlexandruNicoara Yes, is one of the reasons your `onDataChange` method is not triggered.

Comment: @AlexMamo I added a listener to check the connection to firebase from this reference `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(".info/connected")` and it says there is no connection. What can i do in this case to connect to firebase?

Comment: Make sure you have implemented it correctly as in the offical documentation.

Comment: @AlexMamo I followed the steps from the documentation and it still doesn't work. I made a new firebase project but the app can't connect to it.

Comment: For sure you are missing something. Have you set the rules correctly?

Comment: Yes, the rules are set to true for both read and write. What really bugs me is that the app used to work until one week ago with the exact same code that today doesn't work.